# session: going from InProc to SQL session

Tags: asp.net, session

I'm switching from InProc session to SQL server session. Currently, my session object looks like this:

```
public class UserSession{

  public string TheStrings {get;set;}
  public int TheInts {get;set;}

  public List<MyObjectModel> ListOfObjects {get;set;}

}
```

It basically holds strings, ints and several lists of objects. What I do is store this object in the session and then when I need to access the session, I can write UserSession.TheStrings.

Now that I'm cconverting this to SQL session, serialization comes in play. Do I need to add the [serializable] attribute only to the entire class or do I also need to add it to the class definition of all the MyObjectModels as well?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am pretty sure it will serialize by default as long as everything in your objects are simple types.

[SerializableAttribute Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serializableattribute.aspx)

> Apply the SerializableAttribute attribute to a type to indicate that
>   instances of this type can be serialized. The common language runtime
>   throws SerializationException if any type in the graph of objects
>   being serialized does not have the SerializableAttribute attribute
>   applied.
>
> Apply the SerializableAttribute attribute even if the class also
>   implements the ISerializable interface to control the serialization
>   process.
>
> All the public and private fields in a type that are marked by the
>   SerializableAttribute are serialized by default, unless the type
>   implements the ISerializable interface to override the serialization
>   process. The default serialization process excludes fields that are
>   marked with the NonSerializedAttribute attribute. If a field of a
>   serializable type contains a pointer, a handle, or some other data
>   structure that is specific to a particular environment, and cannot be
>   meaningfully reconstituted in a different environment, then you might
>   want to apply the NonSerializedAttribute attribute to that field.